# Adding DataFrames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have DataFrames which have different name's but are all indexed by the same time series. Now I would like to add the values in them. So far I'm using a for loop for this.
If I use `df1 + df2` I get a DataFrame with the same index but with a column for each name with all NaN values in them.
If I use `df1.add(df2)` (with an optional `fill_value=0`) I get a DataFrame with the values of the first DataFrame, which is the same result as when I use `df1.combineAdd(df2)`.

Any hints on how to add the values except for looping over all the indexes and adding the values?

Comment: please give some example data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the index is the same between the two and you don't care about the column names,
just do:

```
DataFrame(df1.values + df2.values, df1.index, df1.columns)
```

Comment: is that different from doing `df1+df2` ? (Aside from throwing errors if there is a shape mismatch.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved in the meantime myself by converting everything to a series and with that renaming the column. It was just one anyway. I'll probably rewrite it to your solution though.